# Postgresql - How to fix invalid hour in timestamp?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I have a table with a field called `revtstmp` of type `bigint`.

I tried to format this field with the following code:

```
  select
     to_char(to_timestamp(revtstmp/1000) AT TIME ZONE 'GMT', 'Day DD Month YYYY HH:mm:ss')
  from
     my_table
```

For the value `1571931942630`, I expect to see `Thursday 24 October 2019 15:45:42`.
However, I see `Thursday 24 October 2019 03:10:42`

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the appropriate pattern for hours, see [Template Patterns for Date/Time Formatting.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)

```
 select
     to_char(to_timestamp(revtstmp/1000) AT TIME ZONE 'GMT', 'Day DD Month YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
  from
     my_table
```